# trying to turn nonsense data records in each column to NULL using for loop in R using R studio, but showed error: replacement has length zero

Tags: r, for-loop, missing-data

I was trying to turn nonsense data to NA. (ex: wage column that has -4, -3. poverty ratio column has -4,-5, character type column has numbers such as -4, -5)

I used a predefined vector to define which are nonsense data:

`nulldata <- c(-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, '')`

then, I created a for loop to iterate thru each column to check if there are data like those in the column.
the for loop I created:

```
for(i in 1: ncol(df)){
  df[, i][df[, i] %in% nulldata] <- NULL
}
```

the error I get is:

```
Error in df[, i][df[, i] %in% nulldata] <- NULL : 
  replacement has length zero
```

not sure does anybody else getting the same error

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You need to [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including plain text example data from the data frame `df` using _e.g._ `dput(df)` if that is not too large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
for(i in 1: ncol(df)){
   df[,i] <- ifelse(df[,i] %in% nulldata, NA, df[,i])}
```

or

```
for(i in 1: ncol(df)){
   df[df[,i] %in% nulldata, i] <- NA}
```

NULL does not set values to NA. You can set a column to NULL to delete it, for example.